# Dynamically add and remove TextBoxes and get value of dynamic TextBox using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem. The code below is for adding and removing textbox dymically through `.append()` and `.remove()`. I want all the data inside the textboxes with a placeholder of *textbox* will be imploded and will be placed in the textbox I set with name of *textbox*. Also the ones with the placeholder of *box* will be placed in the allotted textbox for it. How to do that?

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method= "Post">
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="inc">
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="textbox" placeholder="textbox"/> 
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text" placeholder="text"/>
                <button style="margin-left: 50px" class="btn btn-info" type="submit" id="append" name="append">
                Add Textbox</button>
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="submit"/> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="textbox" placeholder="texbox"/> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text" placeholder="text"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JavasScript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready( function () {
        $("#append").click( function() {
        $(".inc").append('
            <div class="controls">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="textbox" placeholder="textbox">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="text" placeholder="text">
                <a href="#" class="remove_this btn btn-danger">remove</a>
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>');
        return false;
        });

    jQuery('.remove_this').live('click', function() {
        jQuery(this).parent().remove();
        return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: please, i submitted a question a bit similar to this but different approach in javascript. it's much more easy to study than the i han sent first,.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746695/dynamically-add-and-remove-textboxes-and-get-value-of-dynamic-textbox-using-jque

Comment: yeah, its a bit the same but the javascript is different, in new to javascript, so i prefer this one than the first one i posted because its is easier to study.

Comment: Solution is same as http://stackoverflow.com/a/34746914/

Comment: but how can i double the textbox? thats what my problem is, in .append() i can just create another one, but there i can't understand it.

Comment: _"but how can i double the textbox?"_ What is "double" ? See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please! the code for this one is much understandable for a beginner like me.

Comment: i mean, when you hit the button add two textbox will appear placed side by side with a single remove button

Comment: What is expected result ?

Comment: like this, [texbox]  [box]     {add textbox} and then if you hit add text box it will add textboxes like how i demonstrated it and then if you hit the submit button all the data below the textbox with the placeholder of 'textbox' will be imploded and will be placed inside the allotted textbox. and also the one with 'box' placeholder

Comment: _"want all the data inside the textboxes with a placeholder of textbox will be imploded and will be placed in the textbox I set with name of textbox"_ What triggers this action ? _"Also the ones with the placeholder of box will be placed in the allotted textbox for it"_ No elements appear to have `placeholder` attribute having value `"box"` ?

Comment: wait not just below the first textbox but also the data in the first textbox.

Comment: Not following description expected process. Though should use event delegation with `.remove_this` elements

Comment: this will be triggered when you hit the submit button.

Comment: When submit is clicked , place `placeholder=textbox` element values within `name=textbox` element following `type=submit` element ?

Comment: yes, and not just the one with the placeholder of 'textbox' but alse the values of the textboxes below it.

Comment: See post ; used event delegation at `.remove_this` click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
jQuery(document).ready( function () {
        $("#append").click( function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
        $(".inc").append('<div class="controls">\
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="textbox" placeholder="textbox">\
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="text" placeholder="text">\
                <a href="#" class="remove_this btn btn-danger">remove</a>\
                <br>\
                <br>\
            </div>');
        return false;
        });

    jQuery(document).on('click', '.remove_this', function() {
        jQuery(this).parent().remove();
        return false;
        });
    $("input[type=submit]").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).next("[name=textbox]")
      .val(
        $.map($(".inc :text"), function(el) {
          return el.value
        }).join(",\n")
      )
    })
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<form class="form-horizontal" method= "Post">
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="inc">
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="textbox" placeholder="textbox"/> 
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text" placeholder="text"/>
                <button style="margin-left: 50px" class="btn btn-info" type="submit" id="append" name="append">
                Add Textbox</button>
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="submit"/> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="textbox" placeholder="texbox"/> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text" placeholder="text"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: i want to place all the values the textbox with the placeholder of 'text' be separated from the the values of the textboxes with placeholder  'textbox' and place it inside the textbox near the textbox where all values from the textboxes with the placeholder of textbox.

Comment: This is excellent and worked wonderfully - but when i add a label between the input text fields, the "remove feature only removes the "text" field instead of the entire "textbox" & "text" field

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready( function () {
        $("#append").click( function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
        $(".inc").append('<div class="controls">\
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="textbox" placeholder="textbox">\
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="text" placeholder="text">\
                <a href="#" class="remove_this btn btn-danger">remove</a>\
                <br>\
                <br>\
            </div>');
        return false;
        });

    jQuery(document).on('click', '.remove_this', function() {
        jQuery(this).parent().remove();
        return false;
        });
    $("input[type=submit]").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).next("[name=textbox]")
      .val(
        $.map($(".inc :text"), function(el) {
          return el.value
        }).join(",\n")
      )
    })
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<form class="form-horizontal" method= "Post">
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="inc">
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="textbox" placeholder="textbox"/> 
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text" placeholder="text"/>
                <button style="margin-left: 50px" class="btn btn-info" type="submit" id="append" name="append">
                Add Textbox</button>
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="submit"/> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="textbox" placeholder="texbox"/> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text" placeholder="text"/>
    </div>
</form>
```